# Combine n list of lists saving order(Java)

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a list of lists of Strings [each element is in brackets], need to get the List of Strings, each String representing a combination of elements by one element from each list. Need to get all the combiations

```
[+9, +4, +a]
[+i*o -k*z +(m+n+f+5)][+i*o +(m+n+f+5) -k*z][+(m+n+f+5) +i*o -k*z]
[+h*i/o +6*l/8]
[+b/c/r +(a*b*x*y+1)][+(a*b*x*y+1)+b/c/r]
```

need to get

```
[+9, +4, +a][+i*o -k*z +(m+n+f+5)][+h*i/o +6*l/8][+b/c/r +(a*b*x*y+1)]
[+9, +4, +a][+i*o -k*z +(m+n+f+5)][+h*i/o +6*l/8][+(a*b*x*y+1)+b/c/r]
[+9, +4, +a][+i*o +(m+n+f+5) -k*z][+h*i/o +6*l/8][+b/c/r +(a*b*x*y+1)]
[+9, +4, +a][+i*o +(m+n+f+5) -k*z][+h*i/o +6*l/8][+(a*b*x*y+1)+b/c/r]
[+9, +4, +a][+(m+n+f+5) +i*o -k*z][+h*i/o +6*l/8][+b/c/r +(a*b*x*y+1)]
[+9, +4, +a][+(m+n+f+5) +i*o -k*z][+h*i/o +6*l/8][+(a*b*x*y+1)+b/c/r]
```

any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: Try to work with integers. Work with modulo and divisions.

Comment: think at each list as the level of a tree, and each element of a list as a node. your questions is the same as print each path of the tree, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With guava [`Sets.cartesianProduct`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct%28java.util.Set...%29):

```
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Set<String> s1 = ImmutableSet.of("[+9, +4, +a]");
        final Set<String> s2 = ImmutableSet.of("[+i*o -k*z +(m+n+f+5)]","[+i*o +(m+n+f+5) -k*z]","[+(m+n+f+5) +i*o -k*z]");
        final Set<String> s3 = ImmutableSet.of("[+h*i/o +6*l/8]");
        final Set<String> s4 = ImmutableSet.of("[+b/c/r +(a*b*x*y+1)]","[+(a*b*x*y+1)+b/c/r]");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Set<List<String>> cartesianProducts = Sets.cartesianProduct(s1, s2, s3, s4);
        for (final List<String> cartesianProduct : cartesianProducts) {
            System.out.println(Joiner.on("").join(cartesianProduct));
        }
    }        
}
```

Output:

```
[+9, +4, +a][+i*o -k*z +(m+n+f+5)][+h*i/o +6*l/8][+b/c/r +(a*b*x*y+1)]
[+9, +4, +a][+i*o +(m+n+f+5) -k*z][+h*i/o +6*l/8][+b/c/r +(a*b*x*y+1)]
[+9, +4, +a][+(m+n+f+5) +i*o -k*z][+h*i/o +6*l/8][+b/c/r +(a*b*x*y+1)]
[+9, +4, +a][+i*o -k*z +(m+n+f+5)][+h*i/o +6*l/8][+(a*b*x*y+1)+b/c/r]
[+9, +4, +a][+i*o +(m+n+f+5) -k*z][+h*i/o +6*l/8][+(a*b*x*y+1)+b/c/r]
[+9, +4, +a][+(m+n+f+5) +i*o -k*z][+h*i/o +6*l/8][+(a*b*x*y+1)+b/c/r]
```

Comment: This uses sets. How does it guarantee order?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik ImmutableSet does and according to the javadoc of cartesianProduct, "The result is guaranteed to be in the "traditional", lexicographical order for Cartesian products that you would get from nesting for loops", so yes

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The order in the given lists does not matter, the order of each element and the lists to which element belongs should correspond. Thenk you, RC!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. This is untested.

```
List<List<Object>> lists = ...;
int max = combinationCount(lists);
for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
{
    System.out.println(combination(lists, i));
}
```

With:

```
public static int combinationCount(List<List> l)
{
   int r = 1;
   for (List i : l) r *= i.size();
   return r;
}
```

And:

```
public static List combination(List<List> l, int index)
{
    List r = new ArrayList(l.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i)
    {
        List k = l.get(i);
        int m = index % k.size();
        index /= k.size();
        r.add(k.get(m));
    }
    return r;
}
```